# bootstrap hiding grid contents on small screen. Grid > Accordion

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a four column responsive grid which displays as a grid (each cell with a title and content) until the screen size is less than 768, in which case it becomes an accordion, and all content is hidden unless one clicks on the item's title. I have it working with some jquery to hide/show using the collapse method and class.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VKOXJB - top grid

The problem is, to get the content to hide for small screens I had to use the `navbar-collapse` class. This is inserting an unwanted separator, but more importantly, I'm uneasy about using it for something other than a menu, as it may have unintended consequences.

So I tried to mimic it with my own class, `hideifmobile`, but this is not hiding the content when you resize the window below 768px. See bottom grid in the codepen.

Other than that, if anyone has any other comments re the code I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making the main hideifmobile class `display:` property to enforce the setting using `!important` in all scenarios. Remove the `!important` from the `display:` property in hideifmobile class and your problem will be solved :)

```
   .hideifmobile {
        display: block;
        height: auto !important;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        overflow: visible !important;
    }
```

Comment: That's it, thanks! Can I ask why !important broke it?

Comment: Because what important does is tell the browser that this property should override any other property set on it as in the media query you were trying to get it to hide but the !important in the main class was not allowing it as it was set as high priority over normal settings. Hope this explains it.

Comment: Oh yes get it now! I figured there was a conflict with another class in bootstraop, but not my own class. Makes perfect sense now!